# Почему не срабатывает media-запрос?

Tags: html, css, scss

Не могу разобраться почему не срабатывает запрос.

Обнаружил, что если перед запросом на мобилу стоит запрос на Tablet, то не срабатывает, например этот код не работает

```
&-dropdown-facilities {
 margin-top: 30px;
 @media all and (max-width: $smDesktopWidth) {
  order: 3;
  margin-top: 0;
 }

 @media all and (max-width: $tableWidth) {
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
 }

 @media all and (max-width: $phoneWidth) {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 0;
 }
}
```

А этот РАБОТАЕТ

```
&-dropdown-guests {
 margin-top: 21px;
 @media all and (max-width: $smDesktopWidth) {
  order: 2;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-right: 30px;
 }

 @media all and (max-width: $phoneWidth) {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 0;
 }
}
```

Вот так это выглядит в DevTools при экране 480px, он применяет 768px
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Приоритет менял, выше или ниже перемещал код, не помогло

Comment: мм должно всё работать. кажется, Вы что-то упустили, когда делали выводы. например: разве устройства всё таки превышал **480px**, предоставленный Вами код не тот, что сработал в *DevTools*